# Using environment variables for deploy the SPFx webpart solution into the different environments

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, deployment, configuration, azure-devops

I have SPFx webpart for uploading documents into SharePoint. I would deploy that webpart into the SharePoint site collection.

1. I have 3 different site collections for 3 different environments: dev, test and prod.
2. I defined my webpart configurations inside the webpart.manifest.json file.
   APIEndpoints, appids, etc...
3. I'm using the Azure DevOps pipeline(build, release) for CICD.

I should change my configurations during release based on the target environment. I'm mentally tired of searching proper approach on Google. It would be great if you could help me with this.